# Assign onblur event to an inputbox programmatically

Tags: javascript, onblur

The following code replaces an anchor element with an inputbox and assigns an ID to it. I'd also like to assign an onblur event to it, but can't get it working. `newElement.onblur = texOnBlur(this));`
All help is welcome.

```
function replaceElement(e) {
    selectedElement = e.id
    var newElement = document.createElement("input");
    newElement.setAttribute("id", selectedElement);
    newElement.onblur = texOnBlur(this));

    newElement.value = document.getElementById(selectedElement).innerHTML; 
    var oldElement = document.getElementById(selectedElement);
    var parentDiv = oldElement.parentNode
    parentDiv.replaceChild(newElement, oldElement);

    document.getElementById(selectedElement).style.width = "45px"; 
    document.getElementById(selectedElement).style.height = "12px";
}
```

Comment: Is double `)` in `texOnBlur(this));` is your mistake in copy/paste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

```
object.onblur=function(){myScript};
```

you should assign a function to `.onblur` event, you assigned function result.

Comment: I am new to JS so please excuse my ignorance. I tried something like this but without result: `newElement.onblur=function(){texOnBlur(this)};`

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
newElement.addEventListener("blur", function(){
     // do stuff
     texOnBlur(this);
     alert("Done");
});
```

Comment: I agree, addEventListener is the proper way to assign events

Answer (score 1):

You are currently referencing the result of the `textOnBlur` function instead of the function itself.

You should write :

```
newElement.onblur = textOnBlur;
```

`this` should refer to the input element inside the `textOnBlur` function automatically.